# How do I manually edit firewall rules on Debian via rescue mode, locked out of ssh!

Tags: debian, firewall

I run an OVH VPS with Debian 10 and Virtualmin/Webmin to manage my websites.

I got completely messed up by trying to install CSF; it destroyed my firewall tables and locked me out. I need to know how I can edit firewall rules manually in rescue mode to add custom ports webmin/ssh is running on my server.

Detailed what happened:

1. Tried to install CSF, but it threw errors after install using the perl script to check, which left me without a firewall.
2. Tried to run the uninstall script; it just wouldn't run, so I rebooted the server, only then would the CSF uninstall script run.
3. This still left me without any webmin firewall options to use! So I rebooted again hoping the webmin settings I had before would just be used, nope! This was a major mistake. Complete SSH/Webmin lockout.
4. Port 80/443 is working and website is up, but I cant SSH/Access webmin via its port I set or the default 10000, I changed the ports before for security.
5. I don't have any other firewall in use
6. I use OVH VPS

Luckily OVH has a rescue OS that you can boot into and mount the disk. I found /etc/iptables.up.rules which I added my webmin port and ssh port. I also edited the SSHD config to change the ssh port back to 22 (and kept my old port I had it set to as SSHD allows multiple ports) and rebooted the server, but no dice!

I can only assume that this is not where the firewall rules are kept and I can't find it out from all my Googling!

Not sure what's happened when I rebooted after uninstalling CSF, but it's left me completely locked out.

Comment: You can use KVM (virtual console) to connect directly to your system, no need for SSH.

Comment: This CSF you installed, it's [ConfigServer Security and Firewall](https://configserver.com/configserver-security-and-firewall/)?

Comment: @Panki you solved it! OVH have a KVM that I didnt know existed! I was able to login to this, use UFW to re-open the ports now I have control again to try and figure out what the hell happened! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Panki OVH have a KVM option on their VPS, which allowed me to login, use UFW to re-add my ports for SSH/Web access.

https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/vps/use-kvm-for-vps/

Comment: If CSF is the application I've referenced in a comment then it's _supposed_ to manage your firewall

Comment: Yes, but it didnt work, It just fully broke everything on install, and I had to uninstall. The perl checker gave no ways on how to fix whatever issues it had. This is the second time Ive tried to install CSF and its the second time its broken a system because it cant install itself.